# QML inheritance

Tags: qt, inheritance, qml

Suppose I have a few items with same behavior:

```
onActiveFocusChanged: {
    this.state = activeFocus ? "shown" : "hidden"
}

states: [
    State {
        name: "shown"
        PropertyChanges {
            target: myServersLV
            height: 27 * 3
            opacity: 1
        }
    },

    State {
        name: "hidden"
        PropertyChanges {
            target: myServersLV
            height: 0
            opacity: 0
        }
    }
]


Behavior on opacity {
    NumberAnimation { duration: 250
        easing {
            type: Easing.OutElastic
            amplitude: 0.5
            period: 2.5
        }
    }
}

Behavior on height {
    NumberAnimation { duration: 250
        easing {
            type: Easing.OutElastic
            amplitude: 0.5
            period: 2.5
        }
    }
}
```

In these few items the only thing that changes is `target` of states and animations. Is it possible to move it in one parent(super) item as like a base class in C++ and inherit this slots, behaviors, etc in QML?

Comment: Are the components dynamically created?  I'd make the target a property and set it to what you want when you create the component.

Comment: Components are statically written in qml file. I also need to inherit `onActiveFocusChanged` slot and `states` property.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy If my answer solves your question could you please mark it as accepted?  If not, feel free to leave a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the `MyRectangle.qml` file:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: rectangle

    onActiveFocusChanged: {
        this.state = activeFocus ? "shown" : "hidden"
    }

    states: [
        State {
            name: "shown"
            PropertyChanges {
                target: rectangle
                height: 27 * 3
                opacity: 1
            }
        },

        State {
            name: "hidden"
            PropertyChanges {
                target: rectangle
                height: 0
                opacity: 0
            }
        }
    ]


    Behavior on opacity {
        NumberAnimation { duration: 250
            easing {
                type: Easing.OutElastic
                amplitude: 0.5
                period: 2.5
            }
        }
    }

    Behavior on height {
        NumberAnimation { duration: 250
            easing {
                type: Easing.OutElastic
                amplitude: 0.5
                period: 2.5
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it like this in every other file in project:

```
MyRectangle {
    color: "red"
    width: 200
    height: 200
}
```

When `focus` changes on `MyRectangle` it is animated properly.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, absolutely. The Qt docs include an example [of how to create a reusable Button component](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmlreusablecomponents.html#qml-define-components).  Copying from the docs, here's their Button:

```
 //contents of Button.qml
 import QtQuick 1.0

 Rectangle {
     id: button
     width: 145; height: 60
     color: "blue"
     smooth: true; radius: 9
     property alias text: label.text
     border {color: "#B9C5D0"; width: 1}

     gradient: Gradient {
         GradientStop {color: "#CFF7FF"; position: 0.0}
         GradientStop {color: "#99C0E5"; position: 0.57}
         GradientStop {color: "#719FCB"; position: 0.9}
     }

     Text {
         id: label
         anchors.centerIn: parent
         text: "Click Me!"
         font.pointSize: 12
         color: "blue"
     }

     MouseArea {
         anchors.fill: parent
         onClicked: console.log(text + " clicked")
     }
 }
```

To use this from another file, you reference it based on the filename without the .qml suffix.  So a minimal example would be:

```
Button {}
```

But you want to set the text, right?  All you need to do is this:

```
Button {
    text: "My button text"
}
```

Why?  Because they included an alias property that lets you directly modify the variable of a sub component:

```
property alias text: label.text
```

Comment: Hey, sorry! I forgot to accept it, dno why. Really sorry, I don't like when people do it but did it by myself :) For now, I've reread my own question and found that your answer does not contains anything about inheriting `onActiveFocusChanged` slot in my example. I've only upvoted your answer, because it says true mostly but only covers a part of my question.